# I am not able to run flutter application in avd emulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am not able to run flutter application in avd emulator. I am getting the following error when trying to run the app in avd: INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.3.0 (build_id 9786972) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath /root/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/ ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-root/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled for process: 14684 INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each

I already tried to run flutter config --android-sdk, without success. I already tried to install another emulator, also without success. My operating system is ubuntu 18.04, I'm using the latest version of android studio and flutter.